# How to instantiate new struct instance in loop

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to fill an array of pointers to a struct with a new struct each time. The problem that I'm getting is my array of struct pointers seems to be filling up with pointers to the same struct. I'm used to using other languages where I can say new and it calls a constructor which makes a new instans so you can still use the same name but get a new address.
Here is my code for the structs:

```
struct table_entry { 
          _Bool valid; //probably not needed can just use check for null
          _Bool mem; 
          int index; // will be number between 0-63
  };
  typedef struct{
          int proc_id;
          struct table_entry *pte[64];
  } page_table ;
```

Here is where I am trying to make a new page_table instance but getting the same address anyway: I think the problem is within the first few lines of the first if where I am trying to make a new instance of the struct.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if ((strcmp(words[i], "new") == 0)) {
        page_table pt;
        printf("address of pt:%d", (int) &pt);
        pt.proc_id = atoi(words[i + 1]);
        proceses[atoi(words[i + 1])] = &pt;
        printf("new process: %s:%d\n", words[i],
               proceses[atoi(words[i + 1])]->proc_id);
    } else if ((strcmp(words[i], "switch") == 0)) {
        printf("switching to process: %s\n", words[i + 1]);
        int process = atoi(words[i + 1]);
        page_table cur_pt = *proceses[process];
        // change the current page table reference
        printf("process ID%d: %d\n", process, cur_pt.proc_id);
    } else if ((strcmp(words[i], "access") == 0)) {
        //      printf("accessing memory: %d\n", atoi(words[i + 1]) >> 10);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        //      printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
}
```

I have been searching to try and figure out the best way to handle this and I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. I have looked into anonymous structs and I have also tried allocating memory using malloc. I did not seem to find success in either of those approaches, though I'm not sure I was doing them correctly. 
Thank you for any help and let me know if you would like to see anything else or have any questions.

Comment: When you write `page_table pt;` in the `if` body, the variable comes into existence when it is defined, and goes out of existence when the corresponding `}` is encountered.  The variable only lasts that long.  If you need it to last longer, you need to define it somewhere else, or (more likely) use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` or one of its relatives (followed later by an appropriate `free()`).

Comment: @Fiddling Bits It worked! just had to change the pointers and referencing around a little. If you post that as an answer I will accept it. Thank you for the help. I was so close but so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're having is that `pt` only has block scope.  At the end of the block, `}`, `pt` doesn't exist anymore.

```
if ((strcmp(words[i], "new") == 0)) {
    page_table pt;
    ...
}

// pt Doesn't Exist Anymore
```

A way to resolve this is to use `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory:

```
if ((strcmp(words[i], "new") == 0)) {
    page_table *pt = malloc(sizeof(*pt));
    ...
}
```

It should be noted that if you write over `pt` without `free`ing it and lose the former address you will suffer from a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).